# use tls1.2 with python 3.5 and mysql server

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, tls1.2

I have successful made connection from my python app to mysql server following https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

The problem is that i use tls version 1.
But i want to use at least tls 1.2

On mysql server i have setup to use tls1.1 and 1.2 only.
When i try to connect to mysql python complains about wrong version.

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2055: 
Lost connection to MySQL server `at '192.168.99.100:3306',`
 system error: 1 [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1045)
```

print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION) shows me OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
What should i do to make python 3.5 use tls1.2

code that i use

```
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.constants import ClientFlag
from datetime import datetime
import ssl
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)
config = {
    'user': 'user',
    'password': 'password',
    'host': '192.168.99.100',
    'database' : "pizza",
    'client_flags': [ClientFlag.SSL],
    'ssl_ca': 'C:\\Users\\Linux\\PycharmProjects\\Kassa\\ca-cert.pem',
    'ssl_cert':'C:\\Users\\Linux\\PycharmProjects\\Kassa\\client-cert.pem',
    'ssl_key':'C:\\Users\\Linux\\PycharmProjects\\Kassa\\client-key.pem'
}
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
```

Answer (score 2):

After wasting lots of hours i finally figured out the problem.
The problem is very simple. 
I used pycharm and downloaded the wrong sql-connector which only had support for tls1.
By grabbing mysql-connector-python from mysql website i got the right version 8.0.12

So for future , check all version of software you use better .